# I'm trying to install toastr by using webpacker in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm trying to install toastr by using webpacker in Rails

Now, I'm using toastr by `gem 'toastr-rails'`
But replace it by using `yarn add toastr`

How I do setting `app/javascript/packs/application.js`?

This is application.js in my application

```
app/japascript/packs/application.js
import "jquery"
global.$ = require("jquery")

// JS-----
// install by yarn
import 'modaal/dist/js/modaal'
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr'
require("jquery-ui-bundle")

// CSS ------
// install by yarn
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery';

import 'stylesheets/application';
import 'javascripts/application';
require.context('../images', true, /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/);


$("#login-button").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

    $('form').fadeOut(500);
    $('.wrapper').addClass('form-success');
});


console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true)
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs")
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext)
```

config/initializers/asset.rb
Do I have to add something in the asset.rb?

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your 
assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths <<             
Rails.root.join('node_modules')

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css     
)
```

Comment: do you have a node_modules folder? You might have to add that to the collection of asset paths in your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file

Comment: Thank you for replaying.
I add my code in the description.
What do I have to add in the asset.rb?

Comment: did the posted answer help?

Answer (score 8):

to use toastr in rails app with webpacker:

- install toastr with yarn: `yarn add toastr`
- load lib in your application.js:

```
import toastr from 'toastr';

toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true
    .... add options here ...
};

global.toastr = toastr;
```

- create helper method (for example in your application_helper.rb file):

```
    def custom_bootstrap_flash
      flash_messages = []

      flash.each do |type, message|
        type = 'success' if type == 'notice'
        type = 'error'   if type == 'alert'

        text = "toastr.#{type}('#{message}');"
        flash_messages << text.html_safe if message
      end
      flash_messages = flash_messages.join('\n')

      "<script>$(document).ready(function() { #{ flash_messages } });</script>".html_safe
    end
```

- use it on the bottom of your layout file (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb):

```
<%= custom_bootstrap_flash %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This advice assumes you have a `node_modules` folder at the root of your rails application.

If you installed toastr with the command...

`yarn add toastr`

Then yarn will automatically generate a node_modules folder in your application root. This folder gets created the first time you add a dependency with `yarn add`.

Its possible that you already have this `node_modules` folder and you just cant see it. This is because by default rails adds this folder to `.gitignore` which makes it invisible in some file systems.

You can check to see if you have a `node_modules` folder by temporarily removing `node_modules` line inside your `.gitignore` file then refreshing your file tree.

You should be able to see the `node_modules` folder at this time. Add `node_modules` back to your `.gitignore` after you've confirmed that this folder exists in your project.

Once this is done then open your `config/initializers/assets.rb` file and add the following lines

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js']
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css']
```

Then add the following require statement to your application.js file

```
//= require toastr/build/toastr.min
```

And assuming your using `.scss` extensions on your css files then you should add the following to your `application.scss` file

```
@import 'toastr/build/toastr.min';
```

This works in my environment.

Note that toastr requires jquery be loaded before it is loaded.

As such you should make sure that you include the jquery script before your `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` tag inside your application.html.erb layout.